How to to refer to a model that has not yet been defined, how to add attribute in to class that depend on class that created after first
I have some classes in models.py, and after adding one more I need to add one more attribute in to the already created class, I found in internet that the best way to do this is to use setattr() function, so I made all and.. It seems work, no bugs, it is showing in the Admin site as <django.db.models.fields.related.OneToOneField> , but there are no way to chose it when I trying to create or change this field, there aren't , is it a bug or I doing smth wrong?
Here is my code:
class PlayerInstance(models.Model):
    #...
class Competition(models.Model):
    #...
setattr(PlayerInstance, 'choice_to_competition', models.OneToOneField(
    Competition,
    default = 'for_nothoing',
    on_delete=models.RESTRICT, 
    help_text='which competition is it taking part?',
))

And no, I didn't forget to add 'choice_to_competition' in to the list_display.
Here 2 photos of Admin site: I made them, but I can't add them here, can't understand reason, but it is not really necessary.

Why do you need to add an attribute later in the process?

The reason you can not (yet) post images, is because there is a reputation threshold to do so to prevent spambots adding a lot of images.

Sorry for answering so long. I need to add this attribute later because I creating 'Competition' class after 'PlayerInstance' class, so I can't add this attribute at once(because I need an 'Competition' class that is created after 'PlayerInstance').

well, then you use 'Competition' so as a string, not a class reference.

Yes! I just readed this in your answer, thank you so, and for me it seems strange a little that I couldn't find same problem at internet, may be my request was not really good. About note, I have another class called 'Player' that have general properties, and in 'PlayerInstance' I making instances of it, should I rename 'PlayerInstance' some how in this case?

In this case, when this class is used for instances, is it OK to have 'Instance' in class name? Or I should rename it? @willeM_VanOnsem

no, a class typically has no ...Instance suffix, the objects of a Person are indeed instances, but Person is not an instance, that is a reference to the class.


I found in internet that the best way to do this is to use setattr() function, so I made all and.

No. For "ordinary" classes that might work. But Django's Model has some advanced meta-logic, meaning attributes not passed when constructing the class, might end up not in the model.
What you need is to use the .contribute_to_class(…) method, like:
models.OneToOneField(
    Competition,
    default='for_nothoing',
    on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
    help_text='which competition is it taking part?',
).contribute_to_class(PlayerInstance, 'choice_to_competition')
But, you don't need to do this trick to refer to a model not yet created. Indeed, for a ForeignKey [Django-doc], OneToOneField model field [Django-doc] and ManyToManyField model field [Django-doc], you can use a string literal to refer to a model that has not yet been defined, with:
class PlayerInstance(models.Model):
    choice_to_competition = models.OneToOneField(
        'app_name.Competition',
        default='for_nothoing',
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
        help_text='which competition is it taking part?',
    )
    # …


class Competition(models.Model):
    # …
If the model has the same app label, you can even drop the app_label:
class PlayerInstance(models.Model):
    choice_to_competition = models.OneToOneField(
        'Competition',
        default='for_nothoing',
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
        help_text='which competition is it taking part?',
    )
    # …


class Competition(models.Model):
    # …


Note: Models normally have no Instance suffix. An object from a class is always called an "instance", by naming the class …Instance, one gets the impression that the variable is an instance of a class.

